How i can capture the Items returned from "Get Items" action inside a single list to build a CSV table
I have 3 SharePoint lists as follow:-

PostingProcess.with these columns:-


ID


Posting Form. with these columns:-


ID

Street

Direction

Location

Technician

Status



PostingProcessPostingFormRelation. with these columns:-


ID

PostingProcessID

PostingFormID


now i have a power apps where users can filter the PostingForms related to a PostingProcessCollection by (Street & Location & Direction & TechnicianName & status) then click on export which should build a CSV table.
Here is my Power Apps screen:-

and here is the formula inside the Export icon, where i am building a Filter query for the items based on the user selection and call the "SendExportDataByEmail" workflow:-
UpdateContext({varQuery_1:
If(!IsBlank(PostingFormStreetComboBox.Selected),"(Street eq '"& PostingFormStreetComboBox.Selected.Value&"') ")
&If(!IsBlank(PostingFormLocationComboBox.Selected)," and (LocationName eq '"& PostingFormLocationComboBox.Selected.Value&"')")
&If(!IsBlank(PostingFormDirectionComboBox.Selected)," and (Direction eq '"& PostingFormDirectionComboBox.Selected.Value&"')")
&If(!IsBlank(PostingFormTechComboBox_3.Selected)," and (TechnicianName/EMail eq '"& PostingFormTechComboBox_3.Selected.Email&"')")
&If(!IsBlank(PostingFormStatusComboBox_4.Selected)," and (PostingUnPostingFormStatus eq '"& PostingFormStatusComboBox_4.Selected.Value&"')")});
If(StartsWith(varQuery_1," and "),UpdateContext({varQueryTrimmed_1:Right(varQuery_1,Len(varQuery_1)-5)}),UpdateContext({varQueryTrimmed_1:varQuery_1}));
SendExportDataByEmail.Run("Posting",

varQueryTrimmed_1

,User().Email, Concat(colPostingUnPostingProcessIDs,";"&ID) );

Notify( "Your request has been submitted, You will get any email with the exported data", NotificationType.Success );

UpdateContext({varQuery_1:Blank()});
UpdateContext({varQueryTrimmed_1:Blank()});

but i am not sure how i can get the related PostingForm items from the data i am passing mainly; the PostingProcessIDs + Street + Location + Direction + Status + Technician?
here is my workflow definition:-

Thanks in advance for any help.
